# Remove Entries of previously installed windows with wine

Tags: 12.04, wine, uninstall

In my previous version, in Natty I think, I installed MS Office and some other windows software via wine. They have cluttered a lot of places including the Open with and other mime related operations. Is there a way to purge them and remove all wine based entries that now I have no wine program installed?

I want, if possible to purge all entries that have to do with wine.
I installed/uninstalled them using wine. Purging wine does not help

TIA

[image: You can see the MS Access]